# ImportError on Poetry but module installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I'm using Poetry with VSCode and I'm running into an error when running this

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    pass  # build your pipeline here
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/pipeline.py", line 2, in <module>
    import apache_beam as beam
ImportError: No module named apache_beam
```

My `pyproject.toml` is

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
pytest = "^5.4.3"
apache-beam = "^2.23.0"
```

When I run `poetry install`, I only get this

```
➜ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

which makes me think `apache-beam` was correctly installed.

I'm on VSCode and used these articles ([part I](https://www.pythoncheatsheet.org/blog/python-projects-with-poetry-and-vscode-part-1/), [part II](https://www.pythoncheatsheet.org/blog/python-projects-with-poetry-and-vscode-part-2/)) as guide to set-up Poetry.

To start VSCode, I ran `poetry shell` and then `code .`, as suggested in the article.

Additional info which may help:

```
➜ python --version
Python 3.7.3

➜ which python
/Users/miguel/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/python--p5kjR4W-py3.7/bin/python
```

I have no idea why this is not working and have spent a couple hours on this so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

I installed python according to [this](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-we-should-do) article, which I think might interfere with the virtualenv created by Poetry

Comment: I have the same problem and it drives me mad. Things that helped me is opening launch.json and saving it again.
That's really soooo weird.

Comment: Same problem to me. Solved by referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229685/packages-installed-with-poetry-fail-to-import

Answer (score 0):

Outside of VSCode not knowing which Python environment you want to run with, I would manually check that beam was installed with pip or looking at the packages in the venv itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue with you and I can't figure it out either.

What I know is that when python import dependencies, it will look for dependencies based on sys.path of your python. The dependencies installed by Poetry is on folder

> /Users/miguel/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/python--p5kjR4W-py3.7/

apparently the folder is not in sys.path, so the python import failed with ModuleNotFoundError.

The problem become how to add your path where the dependencies resides into the sys.path now? I thought the "poetry shell" cmd will do that, but actually it doesn't. I have no idea then.