# Packages installed with Poetry fail to import

Tags: python, python-poetry

Having a simple yet confusing issue: a package I added with poetry fails to import when I try to use it in a module. Steps taken:

1. `poetry add sendgrid`
2. In a module, `import sendgrid`
3. **Error:** `Import "sendgrid" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports`

Troubleshooting I've tried:

- I checked my project's poetry venv dir, and sendgrid is there: `'C:\\Users\\xyz123\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\nameofproject-py3.10\\lib\\site-packages'`
- Also checked sys.path(); the path to that site-packages dir is listed
- Running `poetry install` gives me the response `No dependencies to install or update`
- both the pyproject.toml and the poetry.lock files list sendgrid

What is going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it turns out it's a matter of VSCode not playing nice and failing to recognize Poetry's virtual environment. I had to run the `Python: Select Interpreter` command and change the venv directory to the one my project is using, then it was able to recognize the installed packages.

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#cache-dir shows the default venv locations for each platform